# Как по нажатию показать блок с определенным атрибутом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, есть такой код, хочу реализовать чтобы по нажатию на `com_review` всплывал блок  `otpr`, но дело в том что таких блоков много и поэтому работает только на первом, как реализовать чтобы функция работала и на последующих блоках

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#com_review').click(function() {
    var ig = $(this).attr("com");
    $('div[atpr="' + ig + '"]').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_kom_zav">
  <textarea id="com_review" com="1" class="text_kom_yts" placeholder="Написать комментарий"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="otpr" atpr="1" style="display:none;">fffffff</div>
<div class="text_kom_zav">
  <textarea id="com_review" com="2" class="text_kom_yts" placeholder="Написать комментарий"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="otpr" atpr="2" style="display:none;">fffffff</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ваша ошибка:* id у элементов должен быть уникален. Когда вы присваиваете многим элементам одно id, то JQuery обращается к первому.

Чтобы обратиться ко всем, нужно присваивать событие по классу.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text_kom_yts').click(function() {
    var ig = $(this).attr("com");
    $('div[atpr="' + ig + '"]').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_kom_zav">
  <textarea id="com_review0" com="1" class="text_kom_yts" placeholder="Написать комментарий"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="otpr0" atpr="1" style="display:none;">fffffff</div>
<div class="text_kom_zav">
  <textarea id="com_review1" com="2" class="text_kom_yts" placeholder="Написать комментарий"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="otpr1" atpr="2" style="display:none;">fffffff</div>
```

Comment: точно, второй раз уже на этом ошибаюсь, большое спасибо